# Png Image instead of Text in PHP

Tags: php, png

Hello i want to show a png image instead of text in my php file for my site.

My Code:

```
function format_age($t)
        {
            if ($t<30) return "LIVE";
            return sprintf("%d%s%d%s%d%s", floor($t/86400), ' Tage ', ($t/3600)%24,' Std. ', ($t/60)%60,' Min.');
        }
```

So instead of "LIVE" i want to show an png Image. I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: http://php.net/gd good luck! that... or `return '<img src....>`

Comment: show your full code. what it is? this is not giving a single clue about your question

Comment: I tryed to set an easy link to the image with img source but it always shows the link if the channel is live.

Comment: Put your code here pleas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to give a bit more background information if you expect to get a proper answer to this question. If you're just echoing the return value, then this might be sufficiënt:

What about this:

```
    if ($t<30) {
return '<img src="/path/to/image.png">';
}
```

Comment: I tryed after this i get blank page.

Comment: Thanks my friend after you edited the code this code is working perfect. thanks and have a nice day ;)

Comment: the quotes where wrong in my example, fixed that now. If you get a white page that probably means that your PHP error reporting is turned off. However, if you can't get something this simple to work I suggest that you first lean the language before attempting building anything in it.